# Writing a good Hashable implementation in Swift

Tags: hash, swift

In Objective-C (and other languages) a relatively good default implementation of `- (NSUInteger)hash` might be:

```
- (NSUInteger)hash {
   return 31u * [self.property1 hash] + [self.property2 hash];
}
```

Assuming both `property1` and `property2` return good values for `hash`.

This doesn't work in Swift's equivalent `var hashValue: Int` method defined on its `Hashable` protocol.

The equivalent Swift code is likely to overflow and this a runtime error in Swift.

```
var hashValue: Int {
    return 31 * property1.hashValue + property2.hashValue // overflow-tastic
}
```

So my question is, what is the best technique for generating hash values (implementing Hashable) in Swift?  Should I just use XOR?  Though my understanding is that XOR is not ideal for creating uniform hash distributions.  Perhaps something more exotic?

Comment: You could simply use the overflow operators (&+ and &*) to allow integer overflows in your hash calculation. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/AdvancedOperators.html

Comment: Good point.  I need to finish reading the Swift book. ;)

Comment: You might want to edit your question. hashValue is not a func. Instead, it's a computed property.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Implement hash(into:) from hashValue in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687214/how-to-implement-hashinto-from-hashvalue-in-swift)

Answer (score 27):

As suggested by Fabian Kreiser one can use the overflow operators to make the hashValue method as follows:

```
var hashValue: Int {
    return (31 &* property1.hashValue) &+ property2.hashValue 
}
```

The value still overflows, but at least it doesn't crash

Comment: You might want to edit your answer. hashValue is not a func. Instead, it's a computed property.

Comment: does it make a difference which one I choose to be property1 or property2?  suppose property1 goes from 0 to 2 while property2 goes from 0 to some big n...

Comment: This approach slowed my compilation time down by a factor of 10000. Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a).