# hashvalue of two objects with different properties is same

Tags: ios, swift, hash

Consider this struct

```
struct Node : Hashable {
 let value : Int
 let i : Int
 let j : Int

 init(withValue val : Int, position : (Int,Int)){
    value = val
    self.i = position.0
    self.j = position.1
 }

 var hashValue: Int {
    return "\(value),\(i),\(j)".hashValue
 }
}
```

My `==` operator

```
func ==(left: Node, right: Node) -> Bool {
    return left.hashValue == right.hashValue
}
```

When I create 2 nodes :

```
let node1 = Node(withValue: 1260, position: (8,694))
let node2 = Node(withValue: 33, position: (257,286))
```

And compare them :

```
   node1 == node2   //true ???
```

Why is the `hashValue` function not working as expected?

Should it be implemented in some different way?

*Counter question : If yes, what is the right way to calculate hashValue for this kind of object?*

**More info**

When I debugged this :

```
(lldb) po node1.hashValue
4799450060528192039

(lldb) po node2.hashValue
4799450060528192039
```

Comment: Where is your init method ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to copy :D Added now!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438210/how-to-implement-the-hashable-protocol-in-swift-for-an-int-array-a-custom-strin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equal hash values do not guarantee equal original values.  The whole concept of [hash collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_%28computer_science%29) exists just for this reason:

> In computer science, a *collision* or *clash* is a situation that occurs when two distinct pieces of data have the same hash value...
>
> Collisions are unavoidable whenever members of a very large set (such as all possible person names, or all possible computer files) are mapped to a relatively short bit string.

It means that this implementation of `==` operator is wrong:

```
func ==(left: Node, right: Node) -> Bool {
    return left.hashValue == right.hashValue
}
```

Instead it should be:

```
func ==(left: Node, right: Node) -> Bool {
   return left.value == right.value
       && left.i == right.i
       && left.j == right.j
}
```