# Create Array of unique Arrays [Int] in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

So, I have loop, where I get `[Int]` and that `Array` may has only one element, may has several elements. That arrays may be the same and may be different.

I'd like to create `Array` of unique of arrays `[Int]`. How to do it? When I try to create by `Set` I see that

> [Int] not hashable

my code:

```
for i in 0..<someData.count {

      someData?[i].db.value(forKey: "value") as! [Int] // here I get [Int]

      //here I'd like to create an array of unique arrays from from the line above
     }
```

Comment: it is kind of unclear what are you trying to do... could you make it clearer?

Comment: Show us what you have try.

Comment: @AhmadF, please, see update

Comment: @NiravD please, see update

Comment: @VadimNikolaev You are adding all object of someData in same array?

Comment: no, I can create new array. May be it will be true, and after that I'll that new array with all variants of arrays convert to `Set`?

Comment: Do you mean you want an array with arrays in it? You can do this `[[Int]]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31438210/3141234

Comment: @VadimNikolaev Check my answer if you are interested in the Hashable implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var values:[Int] = [] {
    didSet{
        var uniqueValues = [Int]()
        var addedValues = Set<Int>()
        for value in values {
            if !addedValues.contains(value) {
                addedValues.insert(value)
                uniqueValues.append(value)
            }
        }
        values = uniqueValues
    }
}
```

values is your array which will hold only unique values.Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own Hashable array too

```
import Foundation

internal struct HashableIntArray: Hashable {
    var value: [Int]
    var hashValue: Int { return value.reduce(0, +).hashValue }
}

internal func == (lhs:HashableIntArray,rhs: HashableIntArray) -> Bool {
    return lhs.value == rhs.value
}

let array = [HashableIntArray(value: [1,1,2]), HashableIntArray(value: [1,2,2]), HashableIntArray(value: [1,1,2])]

let set = Set(array)
print(array) // [HashableIntArray(value: [1, 1, 2]), HashableIntArray(value: [1, 2, 2]), HashableIntArray(value: [1, 1, 2])]
print(set) // [HashableIntArray(value: [1, 2, 2]), HashableIntArray(value: [1, 1, 2])]
```