# Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Array<Swift.String>' to 'Swift.AnyHashable'

Tags: swift, string, casting, xcode9.2

I am trying to cast my strings to `AnyHashable` but getting crashed.

I am using as below

```
let castArray = [string1,string2] as! AnyHashable
Myclass?.functionName!(forAction: actionMethod, forData: [
        castArray:string3,
        ])
```

It is throwing error as:

```
Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Array<Swift.String>'  to 'Swift.AnyHashable' and crashing.
```

`String1` and `String2` and `String3` are the `static` strings.

Any idea why it is crashing ?

Comment: Array does not support `Hashable`.

Comment: Then how can i change to access casting

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438210/how-to-implement-the-hashable-protocol-in-swift-for-an-int-array-a-custom-strin

Comment: @JefferyThomas OP is casting to `AnyHashable`, not `Hashable` actually. Currently it is unclear what he is trying to do.

Comment: Yes. I am casting to AnyHashable not Hashable. Array is accepting to cast AnyHashable but it is crashing

Comment: @paper1111 i want to pass data as castArray:string3 so i am casting that array because string3 also string

Comment: @paper1111 I have update my question. Can you check and suggest for any other way

Comment: Because Array does not conform to Hashable it cannot be cast to AnyHashable.

Comment: @JefferyThomas Please suggest how can i proceed for my code let castArray = [string1,string2] as! AnyHashable
Myclass?.functionName!(forAction: actionMethod, forData: [
        castArray:string3,
        ])

Comment: If you want `[string1,string2] as! AnyHashable` to work, you need to make `Array` conform to `Hashable`. See the answer I linked earlier.

Comment: The sort answer for Swift 4.1: `extension Array: Hashable where Element: Hashable { public var hashValue: Int { return self.reduce(5381) { ($0 << 5) &+ $0 &+ $1.hashValue } } }`